# DozerBeanMapper:Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, java-8, dozer

```
package com.xxx;
@MapTo(com.yyy.MyBase.class)
public class MyBase extends BaseReq

{ 
 .... 
 
 public static enum DisplayCategory {
        Elecronic("Electronic"), Mobile("Mobile"), Remaining("Remaining");
        private final String value;
        private DisplayCategory() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this(null);
        }

        private DisplayCategory(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return value;
        }

        public static DisplayCategory convert(String value) {
            for (DisplayCategory inst : values()) {
                if (inst.toString().equals(value)) {
                    return inst;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    ....
    }
```

When I try to Map I am getting error: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: `com.xxx.MyBase$DisplayCategory.<init>()`

```
MapperIF mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();

osRequest = (com.xxx.MyBase) mapper.map(src, com.xxx.MyBase.class);
```

src is `com.yyy.MyBase` Object.
Have defined constructor as well for enum DisplayCategory. Still getting error.
Using JDK1.8 & dozer 4.4 jar. The same code is working on jdk 1.6. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really expect the framework to create new enum constants through this private constructor?

Comment: No @Naman. I did a further Debug it is failing at dozer jar --> public Object createBean(Object srcObj, Class srcObjClass, String beanId) {
    Object result = null;
    Class destClass;
    destClass = MappingUtils.loadClass(beanId);
    Class[] innerClasses = destClass.getClasses(); .... beanId com.xxx.MyBase$DisplayCategory is not having any inner classes but XMLBeanFactory.java in netsafe jar looking for it

Comment: The method `getClasses()` surely does not throw a `NoSuchMethodException`. The check for inner classes is an entirely irrelevant aspect. The point is, you want to get an `enum` value and that doesn’t work by constructing one via a constructor. So you need to find out a) does Dozer support `enum` values and b) if so, how to you use this support correctly.

Comment: Thanks, @Holger,  - I've found the issue. net.sf.dozer - 4.4.jar doesn't support for JDK > 1.6. In dozer.MappingUtils.class -> isEnumType() ->GlobalSettings.class -> isJdk5 boolean has upto jdk1.6 Only. I've upgraded to dozer 5.5.1 and it worked